# How to ignore single-line if-else statement validation in flake8?

Tags: python, static-analysis, flake8

I have lots of single-line `if-else` statement in source code as below.

```
if i == 4: break
```

When I compile the source code using `flake8`, it transforms them into double-line codes as below.

```
if i == 4:
   break
```

Is there a way to ignore this special case in flake8?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to ignore this error throughout your project, you could add the relevant error code (E701) to the ignore list in your configuration file:

```
[flake8]
ignore = E701
```

You could also control this in a more fine-grained manner and ignore specific occurrences of the error by adding a `# noqa: E701` comment to the relevant statements.